# Elapsed time hours and minutes - start time and end time over a different day

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate the elapsed time difference in Hours and Minutes between two dates/times where the start time and the end time run over into the next day, i.e., a start time and end time.

Example, the start time is **23:11:00 PM** (*illustration 24 March*) and the end time is **02.04:00 AM** (*illustration 25 March*).

I'm using the `=TEXT(A2 - A1, "h:mm:ss")` and its returning `#VALUE` error, the result is negative.

I'm not hung up on the dates, I just want the elapsed time.

Comment: All u have to do is first format cells `A1` & `A2` as `dd/mm/yy hh:mm AM/PM` or if other location `mm/dd/yy HH:mm AM/PM` or `yyyy` even, and use simple `=a2-a1` & apply cell format `[H]:mm` or `[h]:mm:ss` ,, you get correct result,,, where [H] is for 24 Hrs time when the Time rum over next day. In your case u get `3:29` .

Comment: Is the date included in the time stamp?  If the date is not included, **and** the total elapsed time will be less than 24 hours, then simply `=End-Start+(Start>End)` (and format the result as `h:mm`).  If the Date **is** included in the time stamp, then simply `=End-Start`.  If the elapsed time might be 24 hours or more, then you **must** include the date, and format as `[h]:mm`.  The brackets around the `h` prevent a rollover at 24 hours back to 0 hours.  `23:11 | 2:04 =>2:53`

Comment: Are `A1` and `A2` text strings or numbers? (Use the `ISTEXT()` and `ISNUMBER()` functions to determine which). Your `#VALUE!` error is probably arising because `A2-A1` is not being recognised as a non-negative number. Internally, Excel stores a time value which can be as a number between 0 and 1. Neither of the values you have quoted will be recognised as a time value: **23:11:00 PM** should be replaced either by **23:11:00** or by **11:11:00 PM** and **02.04:00 AM** by either **2:04:00 AM** or **02:04:00** (the point after the 2 is an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entries would seem to not have date information in them. Entirely possible, since Excel does not add a date if one manually makes the entry. And since if they included natural dates, your formula would work, they clearly do not have date information in them. So I shall proceed as if this is so.

Then the problem becomes that since Excel has no differing dates to allow the computed value to not be negative, you have a problem. You can solve it several ways.

One is to add dates. If they exist when made but are stripped out later, perhaps you can just not strip them out, or source these entries from the originals, not the stripped down set. And there are other ways to adjust the date idea. `Ron Rosenfeld` gives the easiest solution with his `=End-Start+(Start>End)` but be sure to include the parentheses for the TRUE/FALSE test so you get a 1 or 0. Without them, you will get a TRUE or FALSE for the result.

If you think that might not be the easiest to remember the logic for in a year when you, or someone else, is upgrading the spreadsheet, you can use a simple `IF()` test to craft the computation:

```
=IF(Start>End, 1 + (End - Start), End - Start)
```

That should be pretty quickly understood.

Actually, there's an OLD technique that lets you add a "comment" to a formula or part of a formula. The function `N()` evaluates even a letter input, rather than giving an error like `VALUE()` does. So you can add a piece to your formula like so:

```
=End-Start+(Start>End + N(This part adds one day if the times cross midnight.))
```

It will evaluate the text string as 0, so you are in the end adding 0 which will not change the result of the test "Start>End" and so will not change your formula's result. Yet, in a year or two, you, or someone else, would read it and immediately understand the mechanism of the formula.